# How (docker) virtual networks actually work?

Tags: docker, networking, virtualization

Can someone explain me how these virtual networks work? I know how "normal" networks work, when we have some pc with its MAC adress connecting by his private IP address to some router which has some public IP address, but I just don't get what these "virtual" networks mean.

Do containers actually get another IP address?
Does that IP address translates into host pc address so router doesn't see container and host as seperate private IP addresses?
How can these IP address be different than host IP address if host has only one network card?

Do you know any good tutorial for these stuff, it doesn't have to be for docker, just general about how virtual network works. I tried reading official docker docs about docker networks but it is too complicated for me, I am not that good in these stuff.

I don't need to know details, but just to get the picture how is this possible, and what it actually means when we create new docker network.

Comment: Although your question is clear enough, try to not include things like _Do you know any good tutorial_, in here, as this might get you close votes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, explaining how Docker or LXD/LXC  create and manage virtual networks is a bit long.
This is a high-level overview, I will add some useful link if you are interested in the topic.

In Linux you can create virtual network interfaces ([veth](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/veth.4.html)) that are like network interfaces (MAC address or IP address can be assigned to them), these interfaces are attached to the containers.

You can connect the containers (locally) using virtual bridges ([bridge-utils](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge)).
The virtual bridge can be connected to the virtual interfaces attached in the containers, that is how to create a simple virtual network in a single machine.

Docker or LXD manage for you the virtual interfaces and the virtual bridges to connect the containers (like a real network).

This is a really high-level overview, that gives you an idea of how the containers can be connected locally.
To allow the container to have internet connection, the container managers have to set correctly other parameters like [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) rules to NAT the traffic.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2BS_kuQxBA) can be helpful for a better understanding